# chmod command output: cannot access '/root/server/app.sock': No such file or directory while file exists

Tags: ssh, chmod, github

I run the command `sudo chmod 777 ~/server/app.sock` on my server and it works appropriately and changes the permission.

However, when I run this command through github action, it doesn't work and says:

```
cannot access '/root/server/app.sock': No such file or directory
```

I defined a new file named `hi.txt`. I ran the command `sudo chmod 777 ~/server/hi.txt` and it worked fine and changed permission. `app.sock` is just beside it but the command doesn't run.

The output of `ls -l /root/server/app.sock` is:

```
srwxrwx--- 1 root root 0 Aug  1 07:14 /root/server/app.sock
```

Comment: Add the output of `ls -l ~/server/app.sock` to your question.

Comment: or `stat ~/server/app.sock` and `ls -l ~/server` might be useful too.

Comment: does `~` expand to `/root` or to the home of a regular user?

Comment: @Panki yes it is root

Comment: @LjmDullaart I add the output to my question

Comment: I wouldn't take the error message as literally true.  I've seen processes in high-level languages return "no such file/directory" when the **real** error was "permission denied".  Which user is the Githuib action being invoked as?  If your Github action creates a file in `/tmp`, which user and group are the owner of that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I restarted the nginx server and immediately chmod the app.sock file. but it does not exist. So I put `sleep 5` command in github workflow and it worked correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be seeing a difference between:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/server/app.sock
```

and

```
sudo 'chmod 777 ~/server/app.sock'
```

In the former, '~' will be expanded to the home directory of the user running sudo, while in the latter it will expand to 'root'.

Sometimes.

It will behave differently [if $HOME is set](https://web.archive.org/web/20220901052455/http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) - and use that value for preference.

There may also be differences between how '~' is expanded for execution and how it is expanded for reporting the error.

Try using an explicit path.

Comment: I'm sure that ~ means root. I try explicit path too.

Comment: No.  It means different things in different contexts. It never means 'root'.

Comment: No I mean I check the path of ~. it says it's root

Comment: No it does not. It might say /root when you run it (not 'root') but it will say different things depending on how you run it.